# How to add action button on woocommerce admin order detail page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, meta-boxes

In Woocommerce, I have added button with meta boxes but on click of that button at admin order detail page showing order updated and next function is not getting execute.

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_boxesws' );
function add_meta_boxesws()
{
    add_meta_box( 
        'add_meta_boxes', 
        __( 'Custom' ), 
        'sun'
    );
}

function sun(){
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="abc" name="abc"/>';
    echo '<p><button id="mybutton" type="submit">Return Shipment</button></p>';
}

if ( !empty( $_POST['abc'] ) )  {
    function call_this(){
        echo "hello";    
    }
    add_action('dbx_post_sidebar','call_this');
}
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: **Where `dbx_post_sidebar` action hook is coming from?** This is not a wordpress or a Woocommerce hook. So If you are using a plugin or some other costumizations, you should edit your question adding the necessary details related to that. Without it, nobody can help you.

Comment: Dbx sidebar coming from theme as when i add button  it display button at all post

Comment: Please @LoicTheAztec can u send me proper refrence or a code to submit i am trying from many days .... please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is better to use the GET method and display the result in your meta-box content under the button itself. So you will replace you `<button>`, by a `<a href="">` html tag…

Your revisited code:

```
// Add a custom metabox only for shop_order post type (order edit pages)
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_boxesws' );
function add_meta_boxesws()
{
    add_meta_box( 'custom_order_meta_box', __( 'My Title' ),
        'custom_metabox_content', 'shop_order', 'normal', 'default');
}

function custom_metabox_content(){
    $post_id = isset($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : false;
    if(! $post_id ) return; // Exit

    $value="abc";
    ?>
        <p><a href="?post=<?php echo $post_id; ?>&action=edit&abc=<?php echo $value; ?>" class="button"><?php _e('Return Shipment'); ?></a></p>
    <?php
    // The displayed value using GET method
    if ( isset( $_GET['abc'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['abc'] ) ) {
        echo '<p>Value: '.$_GET['abc'].'</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Once submitted:

[image]